# Can't activate webdev in macos

Tags: macos, dart, sh, dart-pub

I have installed **Dart** on my mac, when creating the new **web-simple project** , while activating **web-dev** i see a warning :

```
    Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
    You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

    export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

can you help me how to find **shell files** and edit them.
best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"` end line of `.zshrc`

or type `echo export PATH=\$PATH:\$HOME/.pub-cache/bin >> ~/.zshrc`

if you use `.bashrc`

type `echo export PATH=\$PATH:\$HOME/.pub-cache/bin >> ~/.bashrc`

you can find and see that file in `home DIR` with shotrcuts `cmd` + `shift` + `.`

Note: restart your terminal after that